# Greasemonkey Script: Show all results from a search, even if they would be hidden by your ignored tags

Tags: script, tags, search

[greasemonkey script to make it so no questions are hidden based on their tags when you are searching](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/63785)

I'm currently ignoring the Perl tag because I don't know anything about it, but occasional I want to search for something regarding it anyway, like seeing the highest voted question in that tag. However, because I'm ignoring that tag, a search for `[Perl]` shows nothing. Therefore if I want to search for something in one of my ignored tags, I have to unignore-it, search, then re-ignore it, which is far too much effort. So I made a script that disables the hiding of ignored tags on search pages.

Please post any and all suggestions, comments, or questions! :D

Source:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Stackoverflow: don't hide any questions when searching
// @namespace      CrazyJugglerDrummer
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/search/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/search/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/search/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search/*
// ==/UserScript==

function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}

var childNodes=document.getElementById("questions").childNodes;

for (var i=1; i<childNodes.length; i+=2) {
    removeClass(childNodes[i],"tagged-ignored-hidden"); 
}
```